# Central Angle in Spherical coordinates using Dot Product

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, spherical-geometry

I have been struggling to find my mistake in finding the central angle using dot product multiplication:

I have two points: New York (40.7128° N, 74.0060° W) and Miami (25.7617° N, 80.1918° W) on a perfect sphere. I firstly convert this into spherical coordinates (r,v,u) for both points and given that the sphere is unit length:

Miami: (1, -80.1918, 49.2872)
New York: (1, -74.0060 ,64.2383)

Then converting this into Cartesian coordinates:

- New York: (sin(-80.1918) cos(49.2872), sin(-80.1918) sin(49.2872), cos(49.2872)) = (-0.6427, -0.74690, 0.65226)
- Miami: (sin(-74.0060) cos(64.2383), sin(-74.0060) sin(64.2383), cos(64.2383)) =
  (-0.4178, -0.86574, 0.43462)

Thus, now finding the angle between the radii OA (O to Miami) and OB (O to New York) we do the dot product of the position vectors:
(-0.6427*-0.4178)+(-0.74690*-0.86574)+(0.65226*0.43462) = 1.1986265072, However if we do the cos^-1 of this it is undefined or does not exist, so we can't find the central angle.

Comment: You swapped $\phi$ and $\theta$ in the x-component

Comment: @eyeballfrog when I converted it into Cartesian Coordinates or spherical?

Comment: Yes, you did not convert correctly into Cartesian coordinates. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system

Comment: So you are saying that it should be instead: (sin(49.2872) cos(-80.1918), sin(-80.1918) sin(49.2872), cos(-80.1918)) for New York? @ChristopheLeuridan

Comment: Your Cartesian coordinates for both New York and Miami have radii larger than 1.

Comment: @blamocur how would I adjust it to the radius?

Comment: The Cartesian coordinates in an appropriate orthonormal basis are $(\cos \lambda \cos \beta, \cos \lambda \sin \beta, \sin \lambda)$ where $\lambda$ is the latitude, $\beta$ the longitude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After numerous attempts, I finally managed to find the correct method to solve this. As @eyeballfrog mentioned, I needed to swap the $\phi$ and $\theta$ and as @blamocur mentioned, the radii was not one, so I needed to divide by the magnitude of vector A and Vector B. Hope this helps anyone in the future.